# Conjugate Gradient

Tags: numerical-methods

Why sometime our conjugate gradient routine never reaches the stop condition even if the result is correct? As stop condition we use the following:

$$\delta > \epsilon^2 \delta_0$$

To avoid infinite loops we also use:

$$i < i_{max}$$

where $i_{max}$ is set as the number of equations to solve as explained here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf (in the section canned algorithms).

Shall we consider the result correct or not? What else can we do to assess the quality of the result?

Thanks.

Comment: What are $\delta, \epsilon$, and $\delta_0$?  This notation hasn't been explained.

Comment: Check the linked white paper please.

Comment: [This paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479895284944) is very related to your question.